# Onlyoffice plugins not working when 4.4.3 (build:7) to 5.0.4 (build:15)

Tags: onlyoffice

When we upgraded onlyoffice server (integration mode) on linux, in-build plugins as well as plugins i customized are stopped working.

It is not giving any kind of errors in console as well.

My observation is that, it is not able to hit init() on my myplugin.js  file.

Please guide me to fix this

Comment: Worked like charm when we discarded current installation and did it again from scratch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you discard current installation and re do it again from scratch.